# Netsuite, how to show popup after login into netsuite account?

Tags: netsuite

I am new to Netsuite and I have a requirement to show one alert message displaying "welcomeuser" after the user loggedin into Netsuite account.

I have tried this client script but its not showing any message.

```
function employee_PageInit(type){
    debugger;

    alert('Dear UserName, The data in NetSuite is confidential and the property of the company.');

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'user role', nlapiGetContext().getName());
    alert('ok'+ nlapiGetContext().getName());
}
```

I have logged in with the role ADMINISTRATOR,

any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Which form is this for? Employee?

Comment: Do you mean display this message whenever someone logged in into Netsuite as an Admin or Employee ? Also where you want it to be displayed  on any customform or custom suitelet page?

Comment: yes, I just need a popup message on home page after logged in

Answer (score 6):

Here is a sample with 2.0. It's not pretty and would need some work. But this is one way to inject javascript logic onto the homepage with a portlet.

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Portlet
 */
define(['N/runtime'],
    function(runtime) {
        function render(params) {
            var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();
            params.portlet.title = 'Welcome Message';
            var content = '<script>alert(\'Hello ' + user.name + '\');</script>';
            params.portlet.html = content;
        }
        return {
            render: render
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

U can try using custom portlet it stands out in the dashboard for showing the content.Then also alert is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this idea in the past and what you want is not technically possible, since there are no scripts that run when you are viewing the homepage. Here are some *weird* workarounds:

1. Schedule a calendar reminder, which can trigger a pop-up with your message.
2. Before assigning their full NetSuite rights, tell users to go to a specific page or form: Maybe a custom record... (the record could serve as a log of who consented to and read your policy) On this form you could have your message. Then when the user fills it out, have a back-end script enable their permissions.
3. Make your text into a tiny image, and make it your company logo for all of NetSuite. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the custom Javasript to display the alert on a Suitelet which would be set as the Landing Page under General Preferences, then once the user accepts redirect to their home page, and if they don't accept send an alert to the admin...

E.g.

```
<script>
    var accepted = confirm('Dear UserName, The data in NetSuite is confidential and the property of the company.');

    if (accepted)
        window.open('https://99999.app.netsuite.com/app/center/card.nl?sc=-29&whence=');
    else
        //Send email to admin
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow the following steps :

1. Create a suitelet script - Login Script with pageInit() in clientscript action to alert your welcome message.
2. Goto Setup > Company > General Preference and under Centers tab add appropriate URL of the Login Script Suitelet's deployment and save the preferences.
3. Note : You can add different messages to different center's based on the roles in your account.

[General Preference > Centers Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3laba.png)

Hope this solves your issue please revert back if anything is missed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the homepage of NetSuite is not scriptable.

There are some ways to check if the record/page is scriptable:

1. Look up the specific record type in the NetSuite Help Center; specifically on the Records Browser
2. On the Browser's developer console, you may run nlapiGetRecordType() and if it returns the record name, it should be scriptable -- please note that the record should be on edit mode for the console tool to run correctly with NetSuite pages

Hope this helps with your development!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this user event script I got from netty.ai:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/message'], function (message) {
  function showAlert(context) {
    if (context.type === context.UserEventType.LOGIN) {
      var currentUser = context.newRecord.getValue({
        fieldId: 'entity'
      });

      var messageText = 'Welcome, ' + currentUser + '!';

      var alertMessage = message.create({
        title: 'Welcome',
        message: messageText,
        type: message.Type.INFORMATION
      });

      alertMessage.show();
    }
  }

  return {
    afterSubmit: showAlert
  };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write a function

```
 function pageInit(type){
     var context= nlapiGetContext();
     var username = context.getName();
     alert(hello+username);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, but you can't just apply this to NetSuite in general. You would have to apply this to some type of record and home page is not one that you can do that too.